# Black-Scholes formula with deterministic interest rate and dividend yield

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

Does any one have the Black-Scholes formula for a European call with time-dependent but deterministic interest rate and dividend yield ?

Comment: Do you mean stochastic interest rate and dividend yield? Then you need to specify a respective model for them, for example, the Hull-White interest rate model.

Comment: No, I nedd the formula with  deterministic rate and dividend yield.

Comment: Yes, I think someone has it .

Comment: For deterministic interest rate and dividend yield, see http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16339/generalized-black-scholes/17023#17023

Comment: In addition, how about the volatility? Is it a constant or deterministic?

Comment: Note that, with all deterministic parameters (i.e., interest rate, dividend yield, and volatility), the discussion in http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16339/generalized-black-scholes/17023#17023 can be applied